# How to create Java classes using the reusable json attributes in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to convert below JSON to Java classes

Here is the JSON

```
  {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "env": "test",
  "envUrls1": {
    "qatesta": {
      "fName": "test",
      "lName": "test",
      "email": "3242342",
      "password": "passTestaa"
    },
    "qatestb": {
      "fName": "test",
      "lName": "test",
      "email": "3242342",
      "password": "passTestaa"
    },
    "qatestc": {
      "fName": "test",
      "lName": "test",
      "email": "3242342",
      "password": "passTestaa"
    }
  }
}
```

Using above JSON body I able to creates below classes.

```
1.
public class JsonConfMainObj {

    private String browserName;
    private String env;
    private EnvUrls1 envUrls1;
}
2.
public class EnvUrls1 {
    private Qatesta qatesta;
    private Qatestb qatestb;
    private Qatestc qatestc;
}
```

*3. In each above 'Qatesta', 'Qatestb' and 'Qatestc' Java Classes Contains the below-repeated values*

```
public class Qatestx{
        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private String email;
        private String password;
}
```

But I need to avoid repeating the above attributes in each class and move them to common Class and map to 'Qatesta', 'Qatestb', and 'Qatestc'.

like below

```
public class Qatesta{
      private Common com;
}
public class Qatestb{
      private Common com;
}
public class Qatestc{
      private Common com;
}

public class Common{
        private String fname;   
        private String lname;
        private String email; 
        private String password;
}
```

**Is there a way to do this?**

Comment: Do you mean getter and setter to convert all the receive info into class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use only One class and give the different variable assigned for that class for eg in EnvUrls1  give class Qatest  assigned 3 different values

```
1.
public class JsonConfMainObj {

    private String browserName;
    private String env;
    private EnvUrls1 envUrls1;
}
2.
public class EnvUrls1 {
    private Qatest qatesta;
    private Qatest qatestb;
    private Qatest qatestc;
}


public class Qatest{
        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private String email;
        private String password;
}
```